# SequenceOf and LazySequence - what is the difference and intended use?

Tags: swift

I'm struggling to understand why there are two different structures in Swift that are almost the same.

- Is SequenceOf not lazy?
- What are the intended uses for each?

Edit: I think I still do not understand what "lazy" in sequence means... F.e. take this code that uses SequenceOf that supposedly is not lazy:

```
    func myMap<S: SequenceType, V>(source: S, 
      selector: S.Generator.Element -> V) -> SequenceOf<V>  {
      let seq = SequenceOf {
         _ -> GeneratorOf<V> in
         var gen = source.generate()
         return GeneratorOf {
           let v = gen.next()
           println(v)
           return v == nil ? nil : selector(v!)
         }
      }
      return seq
    }
```

Let's call it with

```
    let a = myMap([1, 2, 3], { $0 * 2 })
    var gen = a.generate()
    let v1 = gen.next()
    let v2 = gen.next()
```

It prints

Optional(1)

Optional(2)

Looks lazy to me...

Edit #2:

When using map over a lazy sequence it seems to be eagerly evaluating elements anyway:

```
struct TransientView<S: SequenceType> : SequenceType {

    private let seq: S

    init(_ seq: S) {
        self.seq = seq
    }

    func generate()
        -> GeneratorOf<S.Generator.Element> {
            var g = seq.generate()
            return GeneratorOf {
                println("next")
                return g.next()
            }
    }
}

let seq = lazy(map(TransientView([1, 2, 3]), { $0 * 2 }))
```

prints "next" 4 times...

Edit #3. Here is my current take on it: It would be wrong to say "SequenceOf is not lazy". It is rather "SequenceOf is extended with non-lazy .map, .filter, etc". It is entirely possible to write lazy versions of map, filer, etc that would apply to any sequence, including SequenceOf. But, Apple decided to apply the "lazy" paradigm not only to instances of sequences, but to sequence elements as well - so if you declare sequence variable as lazy, LazySequence is used and as such extensions are lazy. I think this is wrong approach and lazy declaration should not be transferred to elements - instead elements should be kept lazy as long as it is possible. It is easy to convert lazy to eager, but not possible otherwise.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is SequenceOf not lazy?

Correct. It is not lazy. That's why the lazy forms exist.

> What are the intended uses for each?

[Airpseed Velocity](http://airspeedvelocity.net/2014/07/28/collection-and-sequence-helpers/) probably has the most comprehensive discussion of the various types. `SequenceOf` provides easy ways to generate sequences from a closure. It also provides a sort of "sequence typecast" to convert one sequence type to another.

`LazySequence` is primarily created using the `lazy` function. Airspeed Velocity's [Working at being lazy](http://airspeedvelocity.net/2014/07/27/working-at-being-lazy/) gives a nice intro. Its purpose is to avoid generating elements before they're actually required, which is particularly useful for infinite sequences, but is useful in any case that you may not need all the elements, and they are non-trivial to generate.

Did I mention you should read [Airspeed Velocity](http://airspeedvelocity.net) if you want deep-dives on this stuff? But it is still worth keeping in mind that we only have what we can infer from the headers, glean from devforum discussions, and intuit from what we else we know about Swift. The lower-level types are not well documented yet, and aren't part of any of the "official" docs, and they've changed several times over the betas. So it's not always easy to know *precisely* what the Swift team intends for them in versions to come. This is the best we know so far.

---

EDIT: As I note in the comments, there is no `map` function that takes and returns a `LazySequence` in 6.1b3. There's only a `map` method on `LazySequence`. But we can build one if we want, and maybe they'll add it eventually:

```
func map<S: SequenceType, U>(source: LazySequence<S>, transform: S.Generator.Element -> U) -> LazySequence<MapSequenceView<S, U>> {
  return source.map(transform)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Airspeed Velocity is my best friend now!

Comment: Can you explain sequence laziness? - still not getting it... Updated the question.

Comment: When you apply `map` to a lazy sequence, it returns a new generator without computing all the values. When you apply `map` to a non-lazy sequence, it computes all the values immediately and returns an Array.

Comment: map seems to be eager on lazy sequences too - see the update.

Comment: You're constructing and using `LazySequence` incorrectly. Try `let seq = lazy(TransientView([1, 2, 3])).map { $0 * 2 }`

Comment: Your code constructs a sequence, maps it into an array, and then creates a lazy view over that array. You want to create a lazy view over the sequence, and then map that. There is not currently a `map` function that applies to `LazySequence`. You have to use the method.